# Value of a NEW variable on a trigger not changing, on plsql

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I'm loading data through Oracle Apex utilities using a datasheet.

I want to make a trigger that checks for a value on the table from the data loaded, and then changes it depending on what it gets.

The table has 4 columns: id,name,email,type

The data to load is something like this: name,email,type

Now my trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER  BI_USER
before insert ON USER               
for each row  

declare
begin   
  if :NEW.ID is null then
    select USERID_SEQ.nextval into :NEW.ID from dual;
  end if;
 :NEW.TYPE := 'something else';
end;
```

The ID works great, it takes a number from the sequence, but :new.type isn't working, it doesn't change.
I also run the SQL insert separately and the same happens.

EDIT:
new.type type is char(1), I wrote it like this just for testing yet it doesn't change...
aah I'm dissapoint of myself, it throws the error just after reading the data and never fires the trigger.

What I was trying to do is that it will have the name of the TYPE column, and put the id from that table into the NEW.type

Is there a way to change the NEW type?

Comment: As an aside, in 11g I think you can just do `:NEW.id := userid_seq.NEXTVAL;`. Don't need the select into.

Comment: are you sure the trigger is firing?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp it doesn't fire, it throws the error as soon as it reads the data, because of the wrong type

Comment: So it throws an error, but you don't want to tell us what the error is?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp it says that it can only contain a character while I'm trying to assign 9, because table.type is char(1). What I want is that the .csv has the name of this type (instead of the ID because it could change), then with the trigger go to the table (table.type is a fk) and with a select assign its id to new.type so it can be inserted on table. It fails because of the type.

Comment: maybe if I could add an extra column to that csv and then change the type depending on what has that column

Answer (score 2):

I see what you're trying to do. You want your table to accept an inserted record containing data that will not fit in the width of one of the fields, and you want to use a trigger to "fix" the data so that it will fit.

Unfortunately, this trigger will not help you because the data is validated before your triggers are fired.

An alternative way to get around this may be to use a view with an instead-of trigger. The view would have a column "TYPE" which is based on a string of length 9; the instead-of trigger would convert this to the CHAR(1) for insert into the underlying table.

Comment: but in this case I have to insert into the view instead of the table right? I'm using apex data loading tool and it doesn't support loading  on views

Comment: ah - then you're out of luck. You'll have to increase the width of the TYPE column on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
select 'something else' into :NEW.TYPE from dual;
```

If this syntax worked for `ID` it should also work for `TYPE`

Comment: it doesn't work, but I just noticed that if I use the same length it works, I'm going to edit to point that the column type is  char(1)...
oh shame on me